# nodemon работает, но изменения не применяются

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodemon

начал осваивать node.js. при изменении файла надоедает каждый раз перезапускать сервер. наткнулся в интернете на nodemon и это должно было решить мою проблему, но как бы не так. я установил nodemon локально `npm install nodemon --save-dev`, и в scripts определил следующее:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js"
},
```

теперь, запуская `npm run dev`, я ожидал, что при изменении и сохранении index.js, nodemon будет перезапускать мой сервер, и все изменения буду происходить, но в терминале на каждое изменение появляется следующая строка:  `[nodemon] restarting due to changes...`
при этом, ничего на самом деле не меняется.

index.js:

```js
import express from "express";

const PORT = 5000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(`${req.query.test}`);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("SERVER WORK ON PORT: " + PORT + "!");
})
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "node_yt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Таки что не применяется? Какого результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: допустим, я изменю `res.status(200).json(\`${req.query.test}\`);` на `res.status(200).json("hello world");` 
мне придется завершить nodemon и запустить его заново, чтобы изменения вошли в силу.

Comment: а в документации nodemon описано то, что вы подразумеваете - автоматическое слежение за исполняемым файлом, без использования ключа `--watch`?

Comment: попробовал сделать, как вы сказали. всё тщетно, результат такой же
https://pastenow.ru/b79751f8cdd43fee30eb3fbe093e2b1f

Comment: попробовал сейчас убрать весь код, запустить nodemon и написать console.log("text"), а потом поменять на console.log("text 2"). nodemon заработал как и ожидалось. похоже, дело в express?

Comment: У меня работает. Вот вывод nodemon https://pastebin.com/0tep7sAY, вот вывод тестовых запросов https://pastebin.com/bjKiKfCr. Видно что сервер рестартился и стал отдавать новый ответ

Comment: решил проблему путём установки более старой версии